# Easily scroll to last page of apps

Tags: google-now, home-screen-shortcuts, 8.1-oreo, nexus-6p

I have to scroll right 63 times from the home screen to get to the page where icons are placed for new apps installed on my phone.  Is there some shortcut to get there?  Some gesture I can enable or an icon I can put on my home page or something?

Google Now Launcher 1.4.large, Android 8.1.0, Nexus 6P

I just found a faster way to scroll through the pages.  If I tap and hold on an empty space on a page then the page will get smaller and it will scroll multiple pages at once when I swipe.

Answer (score 0):

In Google Now Launcher, there is no settings that allows to go directly to the last page. And there is no infinite scroll that would have allowed you to scroll from the first to the last page.

My advice is to install another launcher (if possible).

Answer (score 0):

on the bottom of my screen there is a series of dots, each representing a page of apps. Touch the rightmost dot (63 pages of apps??) and it should take you to the rightmost page where your newest apps are placed

Comment: I have the dots, but tapping them doesn't appear to do anything.